# Self-Made User Object, Wiring in the Templates

Tags: scala, mongodb, lift

Since I have to work on an existing database, I've written my own `User` type for my App. It works fine, but I have trouble wiring in the templates for it.

The [`ProtoUser` trait](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/#net.liftweb.proto.ProtoUser), which I used, provides a lot of the functionality, even an own `sitemap` method. There's nothing wrong with that one, but I need it to be [`Hidden`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/#net.liftweb.sitemap.Loc%24%24Hidden%24).

I've then tried to just make my own `Menu` instances for them. They are exactly like the ones defined in the `ProtoUser` trait, but they simply don't work.

This is my current SiteMap. The full code is here [here](https://github.com/scan/neighr-scala).

```
    val entries = List(
      Menu.i("Home") / "index" >> Hidden,
      Menu.i("Branches") / "branches",
      Menu.i("Ponies") / "ponies",
      Menu.i("Profile") / "profile" >> If(() => User.loggedIn_?, "You must be logged in"),

/*      Menu.i("Login") / "login" >> Hidden >> Template(() => User.wrapIt(User.login)) >> If(() => User.notLoggedIn_?, "Already logged in"),
        Menu.i("Logout") / "logout" >> Hidden >> Template(() => User.wrapIt(User.logout)) >> If(() => User.loggedIn_?, "You must be logged in"),
        Menu.i("Sign Up") / "signUp" >> Hidden  >> Template(() => User.wrapIt(User.signup)) >> If(() => User.notLoggedIn_?, "Already logged in"),*/

      Menu(Loc("Static", Link(List("static"), true, "/static/index"),
        "Static Content", Hidden))
    ) ::: User.sitemap
```

Maybe someone can help me on how to hide that `User.sitemap`? Or how it's supposed to be done, I am used to framework with explicit routing.

Answer (score 1):

Check the class `ProtoUser` of the the [lift framework](https://github.com/lift/framework) under `net.liftweb.proto` where the menu items are defined.

In your `User` class you can override those menu items, for instance:

```
override protected def editUserMenuLocParams: List[LocParam[Unit]] =
  Hidden :: //hides it but still reachable
  Template(() => wrapIt(editFunc.map(_()) openOr edit)) ::
  testLogginIn ::
  Nil
```

or to deactivate it outright:

```
override def editUserMenuLoc: Box[Menu] = Empty //not reachable
```

Then in your `Boot` write something like:

```
def sitemap() = SiteMap(
  Menu("Home") / "index" >> Hidden >> User.AddUserMenusAfter)
```